# Can I pause the download for SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've left my computer on all day and the installer is currently downloading something called "Main Assets 207" with 10.56gb left to go. Apparently this is the 2nd file out of 23.

If I hit the pause button next to the progress bar, is it safe to shut down my computer and resume the download tomorrow? Or will I lose all my progress when I shut down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* close the launcher or stop your computer, without losing any progress. At least I could, a month ago. Fortunately, they do not require you to download something like 60 GB at once !

Comment: Nite that this is only true during the Download stage, not Installing or Reorganizing Data.